# Turing Machine for vertex cover

Tags: turing-machines

Give a polynomial-time Turing Machine which, given
a graph G and an integer k as input, will halt and output a vertex cover of G of size at
most k — that is, it halts with the encoding of an actual vertex cover on its tape.

I know a general algorithm to find the vertex cover of G size at most k which will make recursive calls. How do I create a turing machine?

Comment: Um, is that a trick question? Vertex Cover is one of Karp's classical NP-complete problems; if you could find a polynomial-time machine for it you'd be famous.

Answer (score 0):

The Turing machine "operating system" does not make recursive calling very convenient, but it is possible.   Basically you want to convert the recursion to a loop, which in general  requires implementing a stack.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how to incorporate stack in a Turing Machine? Are you talking about PDA's?